# how to fix : curl_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get records from another database server via API and submit them to a form. Everything is working fine, the point is that I get this warning (curl_exec () expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given). My code looks like this:

```
<?php
    curl_exec($ch);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
    require('/home/users/m/xxx/domains/xxx.ru/a.php');
    require('/home/users/m/xxx/domains/xxxy.ru/b.php');
    if ($just_phone)
    {
            if($key)
            {
            echo "yes";
            if($request_params)
            {
                $request_params='{"form_id": 511175,"fields":[{"id":4,"value":'.$just_phone.'},{"id":23,"value":"'.date('Y-m-d', time()-10800).'T'.date('H:i', time()-10680).':00Z"},{"id":6,"value":"'.date('Y-m-d', time()-10800).'T'.date('H:i', time()-10680).':00Z"}]}';
            }
            }
        else {
            
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Looks like you do not set `$ch` variable at all. You should make `curl_init()` and `curl_setopt()` to create proper resource `$ch` and then pass it to the `curl_exec()`. Examples [here](https://www.webhostface.com/kb/knowledgebase/php-curl-examples/)

Comment: When you decide to use a function, don't you google for it, to see examples, don't you read the Documentation when you find those examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) you must initiate $ch like:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```